# Unity3D: How to play 360 video without VR mode?

Tags: unity, unityscript, virtual-reality, google-cardboard, 360-video

i followed the official Unity tutorial to make an inverted sphere and play a 360 video inside it and i managed to do it but the problem is i can't build the project to my phone because it says i have to turn on virtual reality support from player settings but the thing is i don't want to because when i do that it also turns on VR mode(that split screen view).

what i want is to play a normal 360 video(full screen) and navigate using the gyro of phone just like Youtube. Youtube provides a button to toggle between headset and non-headset mode.

Comment: Hello! Did you managed this problem?

Comment: Try this method detailed in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eaqwszsH6Jg